# Copy Ajax request function, that calls a php function, noob stuff

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I found a JS-Jquery File what does almost what i need. If you click the checkbox it calls a php function. Now i wanna add another checkbox wich calls another php function.

So i tried to copy the function. And change the values but that didn't work.

I'm sure you will see the mistake in 1-2 seconds, so thanks for a short look in the [JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JszZ9/3/)!

This part i would like to copy, also see my tryings in the JS-Fiddle

```
$('input[name="ive-read-this"]').change(function (evt) {
    alert("markiere als gelesen.");

    // We can retrieve the ID of this post from the <article>'s ID. 
    // This will be required
    // so that we can mark that the user has read this particular post and 
    // we can hide it.
    var sArticleId, iPostId;

    // Get the article ID and split it - the second index is always 
    // the post ID in twentyeleven
    sArticleId = $("article").attr('id');
    iPostId = parseInt(sArticleId.split('-')[1]);

    // Initial the request to mark this this particular post as read
    $.post(ajaxurl, {        
        action:  'mark_as_read',
        post_id: iPostId      
    }
```

Comment: post your copied codes.. where u got the error.... not the one which is working..:) :)

Comment: Fix the syntax errors in your fiddle.

Comment: @bipen the one wich isn't working is in the JS-Fiddle.

Comment: @mickylaaaad fixed, works bit better but i'm getting the error message when marking as unread

Comment: Use some debugging tool to determine where the problem comes from. You can use Chrome's dev tools or Firebug for the front end, Xdebug for back end, for example.

Comment: I'm still getting syntax errors, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to add also this:

add_action( 'wp_ajax_mark_as_unread', array( &$this, 'mark_as_unread' ) );

So it's solved! 
Regards